# fix slugs containing invalid characters?

Tags: 404-error, slug

On a site I support, there are a lot of urls containing seemingly invalid characters (e.g. brackets, commas etc) which cause 404s in Google.

e.g.

http://www.anorak.co.uk/167259/news/those_who_cant,_teach.html

http://www.anorak.co.uk/164918/broadsheets/love_thy_(white)_neighbour.html

etc etc.

I'm not sure what's causing these URLs - perhaps the authors are - or perhaps it's something like Yoast SEO. Regardless of which, I'm hoping there's a plugin or some sort of bulk renaming plugin I can use which would e.g. rename the above URLs to remove or replace the commas and brackets etc.

creating e.g.

http://www.anorak.co.uk/167259/news/those_who_cant_teach.html

http://www.anorak.co.uk/164918/broadsheets/love_thy_white_neighbour.html

Update - I did a manual fix on URLs by executing e.g. `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_name = replace(post_name, ',', '_') where post_name like '%,%'`
and repeated for some of the common problem characters (, ), !, ? 
Not exactly automated but hopefully good enough.

Comment: Something isn't necessarily 'causing' these URLs. Google crawls URLs it finds on the page. This could be as simple as a user entering the wrong link URL into the content somewhere. They probably don't exist outside of this.

Comment: Default WordPress/Yoast behaviour will replace any special or non-text characters such as commas and brackets with either a hypen `-` or underscore `_`. As Jacob has said above, these URL's are coming from somewhere else...

Comment: Hm, but visiting e.g. http://www.anorak.co.uk?p=167259 does a redirect (from wordpress) to http://www.anorak.co.uk/167259/news/those_who_cant,_teach.html ... which then 404s. 
In the past I've edited the articles to remove the ',' (or whatever) from the slug and that's fixed them ... so my question still stands - does anyone know of any plugin(s) that clean up slugs?